# BigQuery export CSV: Can I control output partitioning?

Tags: google-bigquery

This statement exports the query results to GCS:

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri='gs://<bucket>/<file_name>.*.csv',
  format='CSV',
  overwrite=true,
  header=true
) AS

SELECT * FROM dataset.table
```

It splits big amounts of data into multiple files, sometimes it also produces empty files. I can't seem to find any info in BigQuery docs on how to control this. Can I configure export into a single file? Or into N files up to 1M rows each? Or N files up to 50MB each?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested different scenarios (using Public datasets) and discovered that export data gets split into multiple files when your table is partitioned and is less than 1 GB. This result happens when using [wildcard operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_into_one_or_more_files) during the export.

> BigQuery supports a single wildcard operator (*) in each URI. The wildcard can appear anywhere in the URI except as part of the bucket name. Using the wildcard operator instructs BigQuery to create multiple sharded files based on the supplied pattern.

Unfortunately, wildcard is a requirement for the `EXPORT DATA` syntax, otherwise your query will fail and get this error:

[image]

> Can I configure export into a single file? Or into N files up to 1M rows each? Or N files up to 50MB each?

As mentioned above, exporting a partitioned table into a single file would not be possible using the `EXPORT DATA` syntax. A workaround for this, is to export using the [`UI`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#console) or [`bq`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#bq) command.

**Using UI export:**

```
Open table > Export > Export to GCS > Fill in GCS location and filename
```

**Using `bq` tool:**

```
bq extract --destination_format CSV \
bigquery-public-data:covid19_geotab_mobility_impact.us_border_wait_times \
gs://bucket_name/900k_rows_using_bq_extract.csv
```

Using public data partitioned table, `bigquery-public-data.covid19_geotab_mobility_impact.us_border_wait_times`. See `csv` files exported to GCS bucket using these three different methods.

[image]

Comment: @stkvtflw Hi OP, I can see my answer is downvoted but I'm not sure why, please let me know if my answer was helpful or not, so I can improve or delete it.

Comment: @stkvtflw edited my answer and added testing using the `bq extract` command.

Comment: Thank you. The solution you proposed requires command line usage. I barely convinced my client to use SQL for his needs in the BigQuery UI, so I need to stick to that. Also, the solution you proposes doesn't filter anything, just exports the entire table. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @stkvtflw you are correct, the options I provided are to export the entire table. If your `select` statement requires filtering, I guess your only other option is to run the select statement alone then use the `SAVE RESULTS` feature in BQ UI and upload the file to GCS manually.